# Authenticating external ADFS users in my SAAS application

Tags: authentication, azure, asp.net-identity, adfs, azure-active-directory

Our SAAS system is currently using standard **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin** libraries to authenticate users via Bearer tokens, as well social logins such as Facebook/Google/Twitter/etc.

Some of our users are asking for us to start allowing of authentication via ADFS.

I'm trying to understand how this can be done.  Unfortunately, all of the blogs appear to dive right into the details without providing a good overview as to what's involved.  Furthermore, most blogs talk about trusting a specific Active Directory, while we need to trust a whole number of possible customers' active directories - and do it dynamically.  IE: customer registers for an account using custom username/password, then provides our SAAS application with some information about their AD. Afterwards, our SAAS application should trust authentication for users in that AD (just the auth part)

Can anyone provide information on what's involved?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

The question has 2 parts,

1. how to work with an ADFS instance and
2. how to deal with an arbitrary number of ADFS instances from different
   owners.

The answer to 1) is to use the WS-Federation middleware, which can be added alongside the middlewares you are already using. However the initialization of that middleware requires knowledge of the location of the metadata document of the ADFS you want to target; furthermore, the ADFS administrator must provision your app explicitly or no tokens will be issued. Hence, the flow you are suggesting (temporary username/password and subsequent details exchange) might be tricky - but not impossible.

About 2) there isn't a way of wiring up an arbitrary number of different ADFS instances unless you modify the middleware setting pretty heavily. The actual answer is that the standard practice for dealing with that scenario is to rely on one intermediary ADFS (or equivalent) that can broker trust toward all others, while your app only needs to trust the intermediary ADFS.

Comment: This intermediary ADFS... is this someone like Auth0 or... ?

Comment: Anything that can broker authentication, whatever fits your scenario best.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @vibronet's points.

Another approach would be to add STS support to your SaaS application. This could be either WS-Fed or SAML. You have tagged the question with Azure so AAD could be an option.

You could then federate with any number of other STS's (like ADFS). Note as stated that each ADFS has to agree to add your metadata.

Another approach would be to use IDaaS (e.g. Auth0, Okta). These would do the Identity heavy lifting for you and would essentially provide the STS capability.

Comment: In case of IDaaS providers, I'm assuming that my clients would need to add IDaaS's metadata to their ADFS?

Comment: Yes - metadata transfer always has to happen on both sides.